# Store and send input data from any website form using Javascript to a webhook

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

I have a block of Javascript code I am trying to configure to send captured form data to a webhook.

```
var name = document.getElementById("pwebcontact1_field-name").value;
var email = document.getElementById("pwebcontact1_field-email").value;
var phone = document.getElementById("pwebcontact1_field-phonenumber").value;
var zillow = document.getElementById("pwebcontact1_field-yourzillowprofilelinkcopyandpastehere").value;

var data = {
name: name.value,
email: email.value,
phone: phone.value,
zillow: zillow.value
};

$.ajax({
url: 'url',
method: 'POST',
contentType: 'application/json',
crossDomain: true,
headers: {
    'authkey': 'key'
},
data: JSON.stringify(data)    
})
.success(function(response) {
console.log(response);
});
```

URL and authkey are configured. The webhook it notified, but the body is empty. The example the publisher of the hook offers for posting the body is:

```
"data": "{\"hello\":\"world\"}"
```

Where the backslash escapes to add the quotes. I need to get the data fields in that block of code between the outter quotes, I guess.

Thank you!

Comment: `push` is not a function of an object, what do you expect `jsonData.push()` to do ?

Comment: use `document.getElementById("pwebcontact1_field-name").value;` to get value of input

Comment: I'm pretty new to Javascript, so I guess I don't know the practical difference between an object and a function. @ZohirSalak A suggestion for how to do it correctly would be helpful.

Comment: @grexlort, thanks, I've appended "value" as you've suggested. Don't think that solves my function error, though.

Comment: after appending with `.value` your `jsonData` should have correct values, you can check it out with `console.log(jsonData)` then just pass it to `settings` object like this `"data": jsonData`. Edit question with error you getting, it can help to figure out your issue

Comment: The error I'm getting is above. It says "jsonData.push() is not a function". Let me try what you've suggested, thanks! Do I place `console.log(jsonData)` somewhere specific?

Comment: try `"data": JSON.stringify(jsonData)`

Comment: I've tried both suggestions, unfortunately I get the same result with both suggestions, an error code: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null". Also, I've noticed that adding the var for the fields, and the var for the JSON data (two blocks of code in my example above) causes the webhook not to trigger. I'm wondering now if I need to somehow build the data input variables into the settings variable.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/5jsbu8n0/ working fiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, check if you're using correct id's for the elements everywhere. If yes, try this:

```
var name = document.getElementById("pwebcontact1_field-name").value;
var email = document.getElementById("pwebcontact1_field-email").value;
var phone = document.getElementById("pwebcontact1_field-phone").value;
var zillow = document.getElementById("pwebcontact1_field-zillow").value;

var data = {
    name: name,
    email: email,
    phone: phone,
    zillow: zillow
};

$.ajax({
    url: 'YOUR_URL',
    method: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    crossDomain: true,
    headers: {
        'authkey': 'x'
    },
    data: JSON.stringify(data)    
})
.success(function(response) {
    console.log(response);
});
```

You should take care of validating your inputs, though.

---

**EDIT after comment:**

You are using wrong id's in the selection. Use the above code but swap the 'phone' and 'zillow' variable assignments to these one:

```
var phone = document.getElementById("pwebcontact1_field-phonenumber").value;
var zillow = document.getElementById("pwebcontact1_field-yourzillowprofilelinkcopyandpastehere").value;
```

---

**EDIT after comment 2:**
Most probably the endpoint you're posting to can't parse the request body properly. Maybe it is expecting a different structure or format(mime-type). Taking note of the comment you made about how the author suggested the data to be sent and the provided example, we exclude the problem with the mime-type and take it for granted that it is `JSON`. So it is in the structure. We need to wrap the current data object(data properties) in a "data" property.

Try with:

```
var data = {
    data: {
        name: name,
        email: email,
        phone: phone,
        zillow: zillow
    }
};
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help...tried it, unfortunately my two problems remain - webhook is not getting notified, and error code is "TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null".

Comment: @tommycopeland Did you try to debug the code? On which line do you get the 'TypeError'? The reason you're not getting the hook called is most probably due to the error itself, it stops the execution. Did you validate your inputs and ensured you actually haven't used wrong IDs for the controls?

Comment: The automatic error code I received was a pop-up generated from the plugin that I'm coding this in to - it did not give me a line. I'm not sure how else to debug it to find the line the error occurs on. I do believe I've validated the inputs in the sense that I know "pwebcontact1_field" input field relates specifically to this form. Is there another way I can validate? The form is on this page: https://www.copelandcompany.com/join-copeland-and-co-real-estate/

Comment: @tommycopeland I don't understand. You're coding into a plugin and you can't debug your own code? Can you please provide your html and the rest of the JavaScript that is wrapping the provided code?

Comment: @tommycopeland Like I told you previously, you're using a wrong id. The ID for your input related to the phone number is 'pwebcontact1_field-phonenumber', not 'pwebcontact1_field-phone'. Same goes for the 'zillow field'. Check editted code in the answer.

Comment: Thanks, you're right, I thought I had the correct IDs, but I did not. I've updated my question with your code, which now does trigger the webhook, but unfortunately the body is passed through empty. So I've re-configured my question to ask the best way to construct the body so it passes through, including the example of how to pass it through provided by the webhook publisher.

Comment: @tommycopeland How did you check that the body is empty? The code should be working completely fine. Is the body of the request empty, or the body in the "webhook"? Also, don't worry about the backslashes, the body generated by the code is exactly what you need it to be. Also, a side question, are you working with WordPress?

Comment: Yes, working with WordPress. Using a plugin called "Gators Forms" (I've used it forever and have too many forms to change to another plugin.)  The body in the webhook is empty, I don't know if the body in the request is empty. Here's what the webhook is showing on invocation: https://www.copelandcompany.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/Screen-Shot-2019-06-08-at-3.56.50-PM.png

Comment: @tommycopeland That doesn't mean the body of the request is empty. I'm pretty sure it isn't, most probably the problem is that the endpoint you're posting to can't parse the body properly or is expecting a different body structure or format(mime-type). Check "EDIT No2" in my answer so I can be able to post code.

Comment: Yup, that did it! I always get a little endorphin every time a plan comes together! THANK YOU!

Comment: @tommycopeland Happy to help. Good luck.

Comment: one last follow up on the mime_type. I also want to access another element by ID on the page, the date/time in the top right corner of the page. This is a WP custom field. I added it to my code like this:
`eventDate: document.getElementById("event_date")`
`eventTime: document.getElementById("event_time")` 
The key is passed through my webhook, but it says "No Properties". What might I be doing wrong, do you think?

Comment: @tommycopeland Are those fields located on the same page? I don't see them and the provided selectors don't find anything either.

Comment: Sorry, no, it's not on that page, it's on this page (where another form with the code is inserted): https://www.copelandcompany.com/events-and-workshops/free-homebuyers-seminar/. It appears in the top right hand corner of the sidebar. I'm trying to pass those two static fields through.

Comment: Hi @zhulien, any additional insight you might be able to offer based on my last comment? Looking to see is maybe I need to do something special with mimi-type to get the ID elements to hit the webhook.

Comment: @tommycopeland Hey, I created a chat sessions because it would be easier to discuss and tackle the problem. Check it out.

Answer (score 1):

Huge thanks to @Zhulien, the amended code that works is:

```
var name = document.getElementById("pwebcontact1_field-name").value;
var email = document.getElementById("pwebcontact1_field-email").value;
var phone = document.getElementById("pwebcontact1_field-phonenumber").value;
var zillow = document.getElementById("pwebcontact1_field-yourzillowprofilelinkcopyandpastehere").value;

var data = {
 data: {
    name: name,
    email: email,
    phone: phone,
    zillow: zillow
 }
};

$.ajax({
 url: 'YOUR_URL',
 method: 'POST',
 contentType: 'application/json',
 crossDomain: true,
 headers: {
  'authkey': 'x'
 },
data: JSON.stringify(data)    
})
.success(function(response) {
console.log(response);
});
```

This is how you can store and send data input fields from any website form to send to a webhook!